# ios - Delete or reset memory used when going back to root viewcontroller

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Good day! Is there any way on how to reduce or revert the memory used to a freshly opened app state? I'm developing a Menu app for a restaurant. On the main screen i have a buttons for Main Course,Appetizers,Soups etc. If you click on one category it will take you to another view, That is UINavigation Controller with UITableViewController, now when you click on any row of that UITableView it will take you to another ViewController which contains UIScrollView with images. This Last ViewController has this code to loop many images.

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                                     self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                                     self.view.frame.size.height)];
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [self.scrollView setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:NO];
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    //setup internal views
    NSInteger numberOfViews = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0,
                                         self.view.frame.size.width,
                                         self.view.frame.size.height)];
        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                           @"main_%d", i+1]];
        image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        [self.scrollView addSubview:image];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updatePrices:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


    }

    //set the scroll view content size
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width *
                                             numberOfViews,
                                             self.view.frame.size.height);

    //add the scrollview to this view
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

So basically in 1 Category Lets say Main Course, i have this

http://oi60.tinypic.com/f1fr0j.jpg

Each category i have that setup of views. Now, The main problem is, when i open the app, it only consumes 6MB, then when i Tap a button, to show the Menu for the selected category, it goes up to 17mb, Now When i click anything on the Food lists, and shows the image viewcontroller, it goes up to 68mb. I tried to add a button on each to and add some actions like this

```
- (IBAction)backToHome:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.view = nil;
}
```

The main problem is, When i go back to the MainViewController, The consumed Memory is there, so the app gets really slow if they select more categories because it increases the memory usage. How can i Reduce or "Clear Cache" of the used memory to prevent slowing the app? Thank you!

Comment: check for any delegates used with strong reference. if you used delegates with strong make it weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling imageNamed will always cache the image in the memory to increase speed, so event if you release holder view(s) the memory usage won't drop. Use some other method to load your images(imageWithContentsOfFile or other) and make caching by yourself if you need it at all.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary* cachedImages;

-(UIImage*)imageNamedBOOM:(NSString*)aImageName
{
    UIImage* result = _cachedImages[aImageName];
    if( !result )
    {
        result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:aImageName];
        _cachedImages[aImageName] = result;
    }

    return result;
}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    [_cachedImages removeAllObjects];
}
```

And then in your code just call it like this(note that you **have to** provide image extension png, jpg, etc):

```
-(void) setupScrollView {
    //add the scrollview to the view
   self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 
                                           self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                           self.view.frame.size.height)];
   self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
   [self.scrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
    //setup internal views
   NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
      CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
      UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                                CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, 
                                                self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                                self.view.frame.size.height)];
      image.image = [self imageNamedBOOM:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                        @"image_%d.png", i+1]];//make sure here you provide proper image extension JPG, PNG or other
      image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
      [self.scrollView addSubview:image];
    }
    //set the scroll view content size
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 
                                            numberOfViews, 
                                            self.view.frame.size.height);
    //add the scrollview to this view
   [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}
```

And in back to home:

```
- (IBAction)backToHome:(id)sender {

    [_cachedImages removeAllObjects]

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.view = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, i understand what you are telling to me, But i can't apply it in my current code, should i remove the loop and change it to the cachedImages? I just only copied that loop to this https://danielbeard.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/adding-a-uiscrollview-to-a-uiview-ios/ . Can you please implement it? thanks!

Comment: I don't know your whole case as we are only discussing memory issues here. Please see my update answer and check if your images are .png or .jpg

Comment: please download my source code, try only to open the MAIN button, i removed other buttons files to make the size lower. http://www.mediafire.com/download/3gpvbf0bp01bird/high_memory_app.zip thanks!

Comment: 'No known class method for selector 'imageNamedBOOM:' im getting this error. i already put the code you're provided on the top.

Comment: call it [self imageNamedBOOM] instead of [UIImage imageNamedBOOM]

Comment: Yes it worked already, No errors, but the image.image in now null. i used this "image.image = [self imageNamedBOOM:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                            @"main_%d.png", i+1]];" my images name is main_1,main_2 and so on. now its not showing.

Comment: Again what's your image name - in the file system? I highly doubt it's main_1, it's more likely main_1.png or main_1.jpg etc.

Comment: main_1.png, main_2.png and so on.  i tried to NSLog the image.image and its null